# How to setup belongsToMany Relation with additionnal attribute in the join table in featherjs with feather-sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I want to add a many to many relationship between two model with feather-sequelize and in the join table, I want to add additionnal attribut. The documentation of sequelize is clear about it: I have to create a new model an use I like this

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {})
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {})
const UserProjects = sequelize.define('userProjects', {
    status: DataTypes.STRING
})

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProjects })
```

But when I define a new model in my feather application, it is not created in the database so my relation is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check if I understand correctly: you want to have a link table (eg. `user_projects`), and map the `UserProjects` model to it, thus creating a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Project` models?

You can use the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` functions, instead of `belongsToMany` like:

```
User.hasMany(UserProjects, {
  as: 'UserProjects',
  foreignKey: 'user_id' // this is what you're missing
});
Project.hasMany(UserProjects, {
  as: 'UserProjects',
  foreignKey: 'project_id' // this is what you're missing
});

UserProjects.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'Users',
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
UserProjects.belongsTo(Projects, {
  as: 'Projects',
  foreignKey: 'project_id'
});
```

And you need to define the `user_id` and `project_id` columns in your link table, as Foreign Keys.

Then you can add whatever other attributes you want in your link table (`status` or whatever else, it doesn't matter)